# How to prevent Google Places finish my android activity?

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I'm trying to use Google Places android lib in my app, It works very well. The problem, when user select the place/address in `AutocompleteSupportFragment` or when press the back button, this finish my current activity and returns to the main activity.

My activity is an activity that opens as result of a `Receiver`.

Code of activity invocation

```java
Intent requestDriverIntent = new Intent(receiverContext, RequestDeliveryActivity.class);
requestDriverIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // required by the app who broadcast
requestDriverIntent.putExtra("line", lineItemId);
requestDriverIntent.putExtra("order", orderId);
receiverContext.startActivity(requestDriverIntent);
```

And here how I use the Places response

```java
private class AddressSelectionListener implements PlaceSelectionListener {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(@NonNull Place place) {
      deliveryAddress = place.getAddress();
      deliveryLat = place.getLatLng().latitude;
      deliveryLng = place.getLatLng().longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull Status status) {
        errorAlertDialog.show();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the error. I just remove `android:noHistory="true"` from my manifest.

Answer (score 0):

override `onBackPressed` method in your `RequestDeliveryActivity`, don't call 'super', instead leave empty (`Activity` won't close on back press) or start another `Activity` if desired and call `finish();` to close current `Activity`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // leave empty or start smth new
}
```

Comment: still finishing my activity

Answer (score 0):

use override onBackPressed() method in activity

try this :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```